# Have multiple widget styles within the same theme

Tags: android

I want to have some Spinners with white texts but I also wish to have some with the regular black text. I managed to change the color of all of them by adding a new style to the app theme, but that would change the text of all spinners and I wish to keep the regular style for some spinners. How can  I do that using only XML definitions? When I change the spinner style it wont work if I select the style I defined.

Comment: Can you share some code like your spinner style and how you apply it to your spinners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **res/values/styles.xml** file:

```
<style name="MySpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <!-- define some attributes -->
</style>

<style name="MySpinner.WhiteText">
    <!-- inherits from above. override just the attributes that need to change -->
</style>
```

Comment: <style name="WhiteSpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
     <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WhiteSpinnerText</item>
 </style>
    
    <style name="WhiteSpinnerText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
 And on my XML I tried to use WhiteSpinner instead of Spinner to open the tag, but the app crashed.